# In form_remote_tag how to replace paramaters Form.serialize(this) with Form.serialize('test_form)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, prototypejs

While using form_remote_tag(options = {}, &block)

```
form_remote_tag :html => { :action => url_for(:controller => "some", :action => "place") } 
Generates:
 <form action="/some/place" method="post" onsubmit="new Ajax.Request('',
{asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:Form.serialize(this)}); return false;">
```

I want to change for parameters in the "new Ajax.Request( ..." code like     Form.serialize("test_form") so that the generated code is like

```
 <form action="/some/place" method="post" onsubmit="new Ajax.Request('',
{asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:Form.serialize(test_form)}); return false;">
```

Is there a way to pass any options to change that or is there a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% options = {:url => "/some/place", :with =>"Form.serialize('test_form')" }%>
<% form_remote_tag :html => { :onsubmit => #{remote_function(options)}; return false"}
```

This would server the purpose as the options passed to html get appended to the remote function call and **return false** would ensure that it overirdes the default generated by rails.

The below would be the sample form generatd

```
 < form onsubmit="new Ajax.Request('/some/place', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:Form.serialize('test_form') )}); return false; new Ajax.Request('',{asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:Form.serialize(this)}); return false;>
```